# I am executing procedure and dose not accept any date from me,and when I am trying to give datetime variale a GETDATE (), it tell me error near ')'

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

this the procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertCustomer]

    @firstName NVARCHAR(50),
    @lastName NVARCHAR(50),
    @address NVARCHAR(50),
    @state NVARCHAR(50),
    @creditLimit smallmoney,
    @email NVARCHAR(50),
    @customerSince smalldatetime

 AS
 BEGIN

 INSERT Customers(
        FirstName ,
         LastName ,
        _Address ,
        States , 
        CustomerSince ,
        CreditLimit ,
         Email )

 VALUES (@firstName ,
     @lastName ,
      @address ,
      @state ,
      @customerSince ,
      @creditLimit ,
      @email)

 END;
```

---

this is the execution---->

```
EXECUTE InsertCustomer
'Liza',
'Tober',
'46 White Second Blvd.',
'Louisiana',
670,
'Liza@visualStudio.com',
GETDATE()
```

Comment: I think you have to first declare a variable, assign it with `getdate()`, and use that variable in the proc call

Comment: when i do this @Now DATETIME  =GETDATE() , it give me an error "Incorrect syntax near '(' "

Answer (score 6):

Can you try calling the proc like this:

```
DECLARE @dt DATETIME = GETDATE()

EXECUTE InsertCustomer
'Liza',
'Tober',
'46 White Second Blvd.',
'Louisiana',
670,
'Liza@visualStudio.com',
@dt
```

In your comment you mention an error, did you try it like this? If so, what is the error?

The point is, you can't use a function (like `GETDATE()`) in a procedure call. So you'll have to catch the result of the function in a variable in order to use the value.

Comment: thanks a lot it my problem solved , but i have a question --> cannot I use a datetime() in my stored procedure implementation ?

Comment: What do you mean by "datetime()"? I don't know such a function... If you mean the datatype `datetime`, yes, you can use it...

Comment: GETDATE() <------CORRECT

Comment: Also, if this answer solved your problem, you can accept the answer. It'll help future visitors.